# Create bipartite graph in R?

Tags: r, igraph

So this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52472976/two-column-bipartite-layout-with-igraph) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235972/bipartite-network-graph-with-ggplot2)... but I cant seem to adapt it to my problem. I am trying to create a bipartite graph using the `igraph` package in R, that looks something like this:

[image: graph]

The code im using to try this is:

```
# create all pairs and turn into vector for graph edges
pairs <- expand.grid(1:6, 1:6) # create all pairs
pairs <- pairs[!pairs$Var1 == pairs$Var2, ] # remove matching rows
ed <- as.vector(t(pairs)) # turn into vecotr


# create graph
g <- make_empty_graph(n = 6)
g <- add_edges(graph = g, edges = ed)
plot(g)
```

This will a create a graph... but im trying to make it resemble the graph in the image, with, say, (1,2,3) on the top and (4,5,6) on the bottom.

I tried using `make_bipartite_graph()` and `layout_as_bipartite`... but I cant seem to get it to work... any suggestions?

Comment: The data and the graph you posted do not seem to have anything to do with one another. To create a graph you should have an incidence matrix or a matrix/data.frame with at least 2 columns, the edges' end points.

Comment: I'll edit the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the graph is created straight from the data.frame it will not be a bipartite graph.

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
is.bipartite(g)
#[1] FALSE
```

But it will be a bipartite graph if created from the incidence matrix.

```
tdf <- table(df)
g <- graph.incidence(tdf, weighted = TRUE)
is.bipartite(g)
#[1] TRUE
```

Now plot it.

```
colrs <- c("green", "cyan")[V(g)$type + 1L]
plot(g, vertex.color = colrs, layout = layout_as_bipartite)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I wonder would it be possible to use this type of layout with `ggnet2` from the `GGally` package? 
I will post a separate question for this.